# ASP.NET 2.0 VB Client passing dateime as 01/01/0001 00:00:00 to WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, datetime, .net-2.0

I have a wcf web service written in .NET 4.5 and it works ok with a website created using 4.5 and our unit tests.

We have connected it to an older .net 2.0 web project and are passing the date exactly the same way, but the wcf service is being passed as 01/01/0001 00:00:00.

Is this an issue with the 2.0 framework? The service is added as a web reference.

We are populating a custom type, the other values are fine, the only problem is with the datetime...

Here is the WCF Type:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class EventType
    {
      [DataMember]
      public string EventTypeCode { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public DateTime  RecordedDateTime { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

the RecordedDateTime is the issue.

The client is calling the wcf service using the web reference and passing the object in like this:

```
Dim response As aResponse = New aResponse()
    response = client.Transfer(request)
```

Comment: It might be an issue with the DataContract.  Have you tried XmlSerializer instead for `EventType`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the .NET 2.0 project adds another property to the type.

In this case, the .EventType.RecordedDateTime returns null to the service unless the property RecordedDateTimeSpecified is set to true...

```
.EventType.RecordedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(infoDate.Text.Trim)
.EventType.RecordedDateTimeSpecified = True
```

Once this is set, the date value is passed without any issues.